# Redirect MediaWiki page to external page

Tags: mediawiki

I'd like to redirect a page (on a MediaWiki site) to an external page on the same domain.

However, I don't want any user to be able to add this redirection or remove it except myself (the admin). I would happily do this with the core/internal files if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Extension:ExternalRedirect](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ExternalRedirect).

The trick is to allow external redirects only in a namespace that is editable only by the sysops and the *redirectors* user group. So, in the example given by the extension, first you create the namespace "Moved", make it editable by sysops and redirectors, then enable extension only in that namespace.

In `LocalSettings.php`:

```
define("NS_MOVED", 500)
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_MOVED] = "Moved";
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_MOVED]=array('redirector');
$wgNamespacesWithSubpages[NS_MOVED]=false;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['redirector']=true;
require_once("$IP/extensions/ExternalRedirect/ExternalRedirect.php");
$wgExternalRedirectNsIDs = array(500);
```

Comment: But note that this extension seems unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Add some JavaScript to `MediaWiki:Common.js` which would perform redirect when some condition occurs.

Alternative solution is to write a MediaWiki extension and introduce yet another tag for such redirections, but it seems to be an overkill to me.